# env = gym.make('stocks-v0', df=df, frame_bound=(5,250), windows_size=5)

Tags: google-colaboratory

## Why doesn't this command work?

```
NameNotFound                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-9928cedc5310> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 env = gym.make('stocks-v0', df=df, frame_bound=(5,250), windows_size=5)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/gym/envs/registration.py in _check_name_exists(ns, name)
    210     suggestion_msg = f"Did you mean: `{suggestion[0]}`?" if suggestion else ""
    211 
--> 212     raise error.NameNotFound(
    213         f"Environment {name} doesn't exist{namespace_msg}. {suggestion_msg}"
    214     )

NameNotFound: Environment stocks doesn't exist
```

.